# How to validate Facebook App ID

Tags: php, javascript, api, facebook

I need to check if the given Facebook app id is valid. Also, I need to check which domain and site configurations are set for this app id. It doesn't matter if it's done through PHP or Javascript.

I checked everywhere but couldn't find any information about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can validate the ID by going to `http://graph.facebook.com/<APP_ID>` and seeing if it loads what you expect. For the app information, try using [admin.getAppProperties](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.getAppProperties), using properties [from this list](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/).

Comment: I cannot find the app URL and app domain on application table.

Comment: Huh. It used to be there, that's weird. I updated my answer, that should work.

Comment: Thanks, it's asking for application secret but I think I can handle the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Graph API. Simply request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<appid>
```

It should return you a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  id: "<appid>",
  name: "<appname>",
  category: "<app category>",
  subcategory: "<app subcategory>",
  link: "<applink>",
  type: "application",
}
```

So, to validate if the specified app_id is indeed the id of an application, look for the type property and check if it says application. If the id is not found at all, it will just return false.

More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

For example:

```
<?php
$app_id = 246554168145;
$object = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$app_id));
// the object is supposed to have a type property (according to the FB docs)
// but doesn't, so checking on the link as well. If that gets fixed
// then check on isset($object->type) && $object->type == 'application'
if ($object && isset($object->link) && strstr($object->link, 'http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php')) {
   print "The name of this app is: {$object->name}";
} else {
   throw new InvalidArgumentException('This is not the id of an application');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it works great but I cannot bring the application configurations, type and other keys do not appear on my response. Here is my test app id 160488080688144

Comment: The link does appear in the json object, right? Test on that. Though for fallback, I'd test on a series of attributes. For example first check if type is available and equal to application, and then the link. After all, type is the documented property to look at so one can only assume that FB will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Graph API:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(/* . . . */);

// Send the request to Graph
try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

var_dump($response);
// class Facebook\FacebookResponse . . .
```

More info:[FacebookResponse for the Facebook SDK for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookResponse)