# Import from facebook using facebook-php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I hv used this for long time to retrieve photos from facebook

```
$this->facebook=new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => $appId,
     'secret' => $fbSecret,
     'cookie' => true
));

$this->facebook->getUser() // gives info of current user.
```

now from october 25 its stopped working ,  any idea ?

Comment: Maybe you are changed appID or secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify your app_id and app_secret are correct.

If you get again this issue,that may be expired. 
Update your facebook app id and secret key.

For verify your Token expire - try this link https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

For more details of app id validate - [How to validate Facebook App ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650107/how-to-validate-facebook-app-id)

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401563/does-a-facebook-applications-access-token-expire

Comment: I dnt understand this , i am using it from February and suddenly something expired ?