# Validate a Facebook App ID and App Secret

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a tool that allow my organisation to add a premade tab on a Facebook page, but user have to use it's own Facebook App and set my URLs in config.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650107/how-to-validate-facebook-app-id) about validating an app with it's ID. But I want to be able to validate that both the App ID and App Secret are good before saving them (crypted) to database so the user can add the Page Tab and I can access the `signed_request` after.

How can I validate the App ID the user provides is valid too? And is related to the ID he also provided?

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all this by making a GET request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/_APP_ID_?fields=roles&access_token=_APP_ID_|_APP_SECRET_
```

If the `_APP_ID_` and `_APP_SECRET_` provided are not valid, this will not return any data. If these are valid, then the `user` ID should be returned in the json object you get back.

Comment: How can I extract this with `file_get_contents()`? I get HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request error. It works fine from browser.

Comment: Don't use file_get_contents. Use the PHP SDK.

Comment: Facebook no more allows direct request like this. It requires an access token.

Comment: Note that the `?fields=roles` isn't the only field you can request. For example, I use `?fields=permissions`. All possible fields are listed on the left hand side of this page, under "Application": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application